# How to solve the isuse in the image

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

[image]

There is a problem of adjustment of ADT tools in eclipse, 
Please suggest me how to fix this issue, it's frustrating..

Comment: Try Window Menu-> Reset Prespective

Comment: @SilentKiller Tried, still same, I drag all view manually to the left side, but after some time again same issue..

Answer (score 0):

go to

```
"Window->Reset Perspective"
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to  `Window->Reset Perspective`